# Cannot write test Quote object for Trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, quote

I have a Quote trigger for which I am trying to write tests.

Here is my test class. However, I am getting some wierd errors while writing this.

```
@isTest
public class TriggerQuoteTest {

    @testSetup
    static void createData() {

        Quote quote = new Quote();

        quote.OpportunityId = '--test-opportunity-id-here';

        INSERT quotes;
    }

    public static testMethod void TestDisplayQuote1() {
    }
}
```

Can somebody suggest and help?

1. The above version gives me error as below:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Opportunity at line 9 column 15

I tried with all combinations of uppercase, mixed case and camel case and the ones matching with API names(`OpportunityId, opportunityid, Opportunityid, opportunityId`), but this error just seem to stick.

2. Since, I was getting this, I use this version of creating the `Quote` - `new Quote(field1=value1, ...)`. So, I updated my trigger to below.

   ```
   @isTest
   public class TriggerQuoteTest {

       @testSetup
       static void createData() {

           Quote quote = new Quote(OpportunityId='--test-opportunity-id-here');
           INSERT quotes;
       }

       public static testMethod void TestDisplayQuote1() {
       }
   }
   ```

But, now Salesforce is giving me another exception as below.

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid constructor syntax, name=value pairs can only be used for SObjects: Quote at line 7 column 27

Can somebody put some light here as to why I cannot create Quote object for my test?

Answer (score 0):

If the code posted above is what you have currently, then you seem to have a *typo* in your `insert` statement.

You are trying to create the `Quote` instance as:

```
Quote quote = new Quote();
```

And that you are trying to insert using an extra "s" in the name:

```
insert quotes; // notice extra s here
```

---

Removing the extra "s" here should fix the problem.

```
insert quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this issue occurs when your organization has a class with the same name as the standard platform class. In your case `Quote` i.e. Your organization might be having a class named as `Quote`.

Navigate to Setup > Apex Classes > and search for a class which is named as `Quote` and rename it to something else.

You are getting the above errors due to following reasons

- In your first attempt, compiler searches for the `OpportunityId` property in your custom made class which it can't find and hence gives you compilation error.
- In your second attempt, compiler searches for the Constructor with parameters in your custom made class which it can't find and hence gives you compilation error.

**You should never create classes with the names which are already being used by the platform.**

Once you rename your custom made `Quote` class to something else, make sure to compile all your classes by navigating to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Click on **Compile all classes** and then try saving your above class.

Also, one more compilation issue which you need to correct is, you are using uninitialized variable `quotes` to perform `DML` which again will give you compilation error. You should use `quote` i.e. the variable which you initialized as an instance of `Quote` to perform DML i.e replace `insert quotes` to `insert quote`. Once you compile all your classes and fix the above issue, your class should be saved successfully.

Note : Apex is case insensitive, so you don't have to worry about case while writing code in apex.

Comment: Hi @Samridhi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.